# PowerShell verb for "Expire"

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm in the midst of finalising the set of cmdlets for a server application. Part of the application includes security principal management and data object management, and "expiration" of both (timed and manual). After the expiration date, login and access for the security principal is refused and access to the data owned by that principal is optionally prevented (either immediately by deletion or as part of automatic maintenance by marking it as expired).

From the output of Get-Verb, I cannot see an obvious synonym for Expire, which is the most natural choice of verb for the action being undertaken here. Expire on a security principal expires the principal and may also expire all their stored data, while expire of a data object is restricted to that object.

Set- is already in use for both object types, and has a partial overlap in functionality (Expire- forces a date in the past, and removes data, while Set- will allow future or past dates but NOT remove the data).

In this fashion Expire is combining two operations (Set+Remove) and for data-security reasons, we wouldn't want to force separation into the two operations (that's already possible).

For this reason, I also consider that Disable- is not appropriate since it suggests the possibility of reversal with Enable-.

I also think Remove- by itself is inappropriate since there are data records specifically **not** deleted as part of the operation.

Unpublish seems very close at least for the data, but again it seems that the intent is for Unpublish and Publish to be paired, and in this case it would not be reversible. It also does not make sense when applied to the security principal.

So which (if any) standard verb would you expect to use, if you wanted to expire something?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the list of [approved verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), two jump out at me:

> Deny (dn):
>   Refuses, objects, blocks, or opposes the state of a resource or process.
>
> Revoke (rk): Specifies an action that does not allow access to a resource. This verb is paired with Grant.

I wouldn't worry too much if there is not a paired operation, since that happens with some of the built-in cmdlets. `Stop-Computer`, for example, has no paired `Start-Computer`. There is `Remove-Variable`, but no `Add-Variable` (there is `New-Variable`). I think that it is only important if a paired command exists that it is named consistently.

Another option may be to use something like a `Set-ObjectExpiration`/`Get-ObjectExpiration` especially, if it makes sense to want to query when objects are going to expire.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not entirely opposed to Revoke, especially for the security principal. It's not entirely accurate though, and for data it doesn't really make sense since it's not the access **to** the data, it is the data object itself being expunged. Good thought though.

Comment: @DavidRa Maybe what you have is two completely different verbs (e.g. Revoke-Principal and Remove-Data) that have parameters that indicate if the effect is immediate or delayed.

Comment: I think Revoke-Principal is close enough (it already takes a SwitchParameter for whether to also expunge the data). But Remove-Data / Deny-Data doesn't feel right. At this point, though, I may be splitting hairs. If it weren't for PSH's idiotic insistence on showing warning messages for "non-approved" verbs, I'd not even have asked the question in the first place since the cmdlet would be found with any number of GCM commands - gcm Product, gcm Datatype, gcm User would all find the product related cmdlets, and the get-help output will be/is comprehensive.

Comment: If not for "idiotic" warning, we would not have consistent environment. There is simple way around it though: name your cmdlets correctly (with approved verbs) and if your domain requires verb that is not on the list, use alias instead. You get the best of both worlds than: people who know domain will find command (with alias), and common verb will keep it discoverable for people who just use PowerShell and don't want to have Delete-, Remove-, Vanish-... ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about `Invoke`? It could be `Invoke-ExpireAppObject` Or something like that.

There really isn't an approved verb that fits your scenario based on [MS reccomendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 because in this case the word *Expire* is in the command name. If users think of *Expire* they rather search for commands `*Expire*` than for some approved verbs that do not fit the bill in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use `Invoke-Xyz` too often. The concept of `ApprovedVerb-Noun` is very good but the approved vocabulary is very poor.